# mongoose insert decimal128 data in db saved as string for required nested documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, decimal

for this example:
data set `books.json` file:

```
  [
    {
        "addr": "address1",
        "book": "book1",
        "rawPrice": "9.135027",
        "prices": [
          {"net": "9.135027"},
          {"gross": "10.15003"}
        ],
        "price": {
          "net": "9.135027",
          "gross": "10.15003"
        }
    },
    {
        "addr": "address2",
        "book": "book1",
        "rawPrice": "19.351017",
        "prices": [
          {"net": "19.351017"},
          {"gross": "21.50113"}
        ],
        "price": {
          "net": "19.351017",
          "gross": "21.50113"
        }
    }
  ]
```

insertion code `app.ts` file:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { model, connect, Schema } from 'mongoose';

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db-tests';

const log = (data: any) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
const data = readFileSync('./books.json', { encoding:'utf8', flag:'r' });
const decimalField = {
  default: 0,
  required: true,
  type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  get: (v: Schema.Types.Decimal128) => v.toString(),
};
const decimalOptionalField = {
  default: 0,
  type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  get: (v: Schema.Types.Decimal128) => v.toString(),
};
const booksScema = new Schema(
  {
    addr: { $type: String },
    book: { $type: String },
    rawPrice: decimalField,
    price: {
      required: true,
      type: {
        net: decimalField,
        gross: decimalField,
      },
    },
    prices: {
      required: true,
      type: [
        {
          net: decimalOptionalField,
          gross: decimalOptionalField,
        }
      ],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true, versionKey: false }
);

connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then((mongoose) => {
  const booksModel = model('books', booksScema);
  booksModel.insertMany(JSON.parse(data)).then((insertedData) => {
    log(insertedData);
    mongoose.connection.close();
  });
});
```

result in data inserted in db like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("60006333e861c6c0b10778be"),
    "rawPrice" : NumberDecimal("9.135027"),
    "prices" : [ 
      {
        "net" : NumberDecimal("9.135027"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("60006333e861c6c0b10778bf")
      }, 
      {
        "gross" : NumberDecimal("10.15003"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("60006333e861c6c0b10778c0")
      }
    ],
    "price" : {
      "net" : "9.135027",
      "gross" : "10.15003"
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-14T15:28:51.810Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-14T15:28:51.810Z")
  }
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("60006333e861c6c0b10778c1"),
    "rawPrice" : NumberDecimal("19.351017"),
    "prices" : [ 
      {
        "net" : NumberDecimal("19.351017"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("60006333e861c6c0b10778c2")
      }, 
      {
        "gross" : NumberDecimal("21.50113"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("60006333e861c6c0b10778c3")
      }
    ],
    "price" : {
      "net" : "19.351017",
      "gross" : "21.50113"
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-14T15:28:51.812Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-14T15:28:51.812Z")
  }
]
```

As shown in the result the fields `rawPrice` and `prices` have correct values with type `Decimal128`, but for the nested document `price` it's of incorrect type the value is saved as string.
But when the price is defined in the schema without the detailed object like this:

```
price: {
  net: decimalOptionalField,
  gross: decimalOptionalField,
},
```

I get the correct result:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("600064b60d223c13635a22dd"),
    "price" : {
      "net" : NumberDecimal("9.135027"),
      "gross" : NumberDecimal("10.15003")
    },
    "rawPrice" : NumberDecimal("9.135027"),
    "prices" : [ 
      {
        "net" : NumberDecimal("9.135027"),
        "gross" : NumberDecimal("0"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("600064b60d223c13635a22de")
      }, 
      {
        "net" : NumberDecimal("0"),
        "gross" : NumberDecimal("10.15003"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("600064b60d223c13635a22df")
      }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-14T15:35:18.452Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-14T15:35:18.452Z")
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("600064b60d223c13635a22e0"),
    "price" : {
      "net" : NumberDecimal("19.351017"),
      "gross" : NumberDecimal("21.50113")
    },
    "rawPrice" : NumberDecimal("19.351017"),
    "prices" : [ 
      {
        "net" : NumberDecimal("19.351017"),
        "gross" : NumberDecimal("0"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("600064b60d223c13635a22e1")
      }, 
      {
        "net" : NumberDecimal("0"),
        "gross" : NumberDecimal("21.50113"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("600064b60d223c13635a22e2")
      }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-14T15:35:18.454Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-14T15:35:18.454Z")
  }
]
```

But I need that field to be required.
So, how can I make sure the value is saved as `Decimal128` instead while make it required too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in your schema vs your dataset and you're running against an exception in Mongoose 5+ where `price` becomes a `Mixed` path.

First, check whether you want [nested path or subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments-versus-nested-paths). Here you kinda tried to get both. If we assume, you want the same result as in `prices` (nested documents), then your schema would look like this.

```
const decimalField = {
  default: 0,
  required: true,
  type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  get: (v: Schema.Types.Decimal128) => v.toString(),
};

const priceSchema = new Schema({
  net: decimalField,
  gross: decimalField,
});

const booksScema = new Schema(
  {
    addr: String,
    book: String ,
    rawPrice: decimalField,
    price: priceSchema,
    prices: {
      type: priceSchema,
      validate: (v: any) => Array.isArray(v) && v.length > 0,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
    // useNestedStrict: true, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#useNestedStrict
    // strict: 'throw',
  }
);
```

or instead you could use the option `typePojoToMixed: false` like this:

```
const decimalField = {
  default: 0,
  required: true,
  type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  get: (v: Schema.Types.Decimal128) => v.toString(),
};
const decimalOptionalField = {
  default: 0,
  type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  get: (v: Schema.Types.Decimal128) => v.toString()
};
const booksScema = new Schema(
  {
    addr: String,
    book: String ,
    rawPrice: decimalField,
    price: {
      required: true,
      type: {
        net: decimalField,
        gross: decimalField,
      },
    },
    prices: {
      required: true,
      type: [
        {
          net: decimalOptionalField,
          gross: decimalOptionalField,
        }
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
    typePojoToMixed: false,
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the link, I ended up using the `typePojoToMixed: false` option, it looked simpler than creating new schema for every nested field.